# UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath displays duplicate cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where I move a row from outside the visible scroll area to the top of the `UITableView`. The animation works as intended but it ends up showing a duplicate cell of what was previously at index 0.

Code looks something like this except for the hardcoded index:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:16 inSection:0] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I have this problem on both iOS 8 & iOS 7. Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was a bug in the re-ordering of my data provider. I moved a cell in the tableview but the data array did not reflect that change.